# How can I enable audio recording of keyboard dictation sounds?

Tags: ios, keyboard, audio, voice-dictation, screen-recording

I have an irritating problem using iOS 14 keyboard dictation*. So, I've tried to reproduce the problem and record the behaviour using Screen Recorder.

My problem is that once the keyboard is listening for my speech, the video recording's audio track goes silent.

Is there any way I can edit the exception rules to the audio recording?

**Footnotes**

*Yes, I have an X/Y problem. As soon as I can suitably demonstrate the problem with an audio/video recording, I will post a new question

Comment: No worries on the X Y - one clear question linked to a second is the way to go. Then if needed a third question to synthesize a “fix” if it’s not clear how to chain the two together is also perfectly fine.

Comment: This isn't actually XY. I'd call it the 'ABC recursion' but the interwebz seems to like calling it 'Yak shaving'. You need to solve problem A. However, in order to solve problem A you discover you first need to solve problem B. In order to solve problem B, you first need to complete C… Sometimes my days seem an endless series of these ;)

Comment: On iOS, this may be “jailbreak” as table stakes. macOS allows access to the audio routing at a low enough level and I’ll be pleasantly surprised (or potentially shocked) if there’s any access to the microphone at this low a level. Or you’ll have to do like the pros do and use an external camera and mic to record your interaction.